# Google Classroom API - studentSubmission - comment, grade, respond

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

Big picture - I want to build a bot to respond to my students on SHORT_ANSWER_QUESTION assignments -- I'm running into a couple of hurtles, but the biggest at this time is that there doesn't seem to be a way to give a comment along with a grade.

Does anyone know how to patch a comment or response of some sort to a student's submission?

Relevant documentation: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently there is no way to directly do this in the [studentSubmisson context](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#StudentSubmission). There's the option to Grade student responses, but this only allows for numeric values.

There already is a Feature Request filed on Issue Tracker related to this issue. You can find it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36882823). I suggest upvoting it to give it more visibility.